# Firebase, getValue is annotated as nullable for log in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to log in, it just crashes. I realized that the problem is in getValue(___.class) when it checks the password but when i get the value from Firebase the value is null, have tried more or less every answer here but got no success. How can I correct the code? Please help!

**module Users**

```
package com.example.assistant.Module;

public class Users {
    private String userName, password;

    public Users() {

    }

    public Users(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**main problem area**

```
private void ValidateUser(String userName, String password) {
        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(userName).exists()) {
                    Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(userName).getValue(Users.class);

                    if (usersData.getUserName().equals(userName)) {
                        if (usersData.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                            if (parentDbName.equals("Users")){
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(homeIntent);
                            }
                            else if (parentDbName.equals("Admins")){
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminAddNewProductActivity.class);
                                startActivity(homeIntent);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

parentDbName = "Users" default

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.assistant, PID: 2759
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.assistant.MainActivity$6.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:123)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Just add a null check for `parentDbName`?

Comment: It cannot be empty, the code must match whether the user entered the correct password to confirm the login to the account. And instead of this, he does not take anything from the database.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Besides that, what are the values of `parentDbName` and `userName` inside the child() calls? Please respond with @AlexMamo